CoreDNS pod waits on kubernetes indefinitely, fails to start
I have recently attempted to setup a 3-node Kubernetes cluster using calico (installed with tigera-operator.yaml). However, when doing so, only one of the two coreDNS services functions correctly.
$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-8445fcc4f-jknn4                            0/1     Running   0          15s
coredns-8445fcc4f-q9fhg                            1/1     Running   0          15s
...

One waits indefinitely trying to contact the Kubernetes API server, while the other has no issue doing so. Here are the logs of the faulty node.
$ kubectl logs coredns-8445fcc4f-jknn4 -n kube-system
[INFO] plugin/kubernetes: waiting for Kubernetes API before starting server
[INFO] plugin/kubernetes: waiting for Kubernetes API before starting server
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
[INFO] plugin/kubernetes: waiting for Kubernetes API before starting server
[INFO] plugin/kubernetes: waiting for Kubernetes API before starting server
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
[INFO] plugin/kubernetes: waiting for Kubernetes API before starting server
[INFO] plugin/kubernetes: waiting for Kubernetes API before starting server
[INFO] plugin/kubernetes: waiting for Kubernetes API before starting server
[INFO] plugin/kubernetes: waiting for Kubernetes API before starting server
[INFO] plugin/kubernetes: waiting for Kubernetes API before starting server
[WARNING] plugin/kubernetes: starting server with unsynced Kubernetes API

The coredns configmap is as follows:
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        log
        errors
        health {
           lameduck 5s
        }
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
           pods insecure
           fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
           ttl 30
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf {
           max_concurrent 1000
        }
        cache 30
        #loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2024-06-25T20:06:12Z"
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "1261664"
  uid: f0837e49-308b-4167-89af-1a182a81aea4

I have verified that the DNS containers have the appropriate permissions and endpoints, as per the instructions in the DNS debugging page on the kubernetes website. I have also commented out the "loop" term from the coreDNS configmap, in line with the advice from this SO answer, but the container remains unable to contact kubernetes.
EDIT: Upon further inspection, it's become clear that, when pods are scheduled to a particular node in the system, they are incapable of reaching the API server address. Can anyone suggest potential steps to help debug this?

The issue ended up involving the DNS CIDR. When I originally initialized the cluster, I used the following command:
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.0.0.0/8

However, the pod network CIDR should be disjoint from the IP addresses of the nodes, and, since my nodes fell into the 10.0.0.0/8 range, a variety of network errors resulted. Restarting the cluster with --pod-network-cidr=10.0.0.0/16 (and editing calico's custom resource YAML file to reflect this new CIDR) fixed my issues.
